# Conjecture about prime numbers and fibonacci numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, conjectures

I have done a few (not extensive) numerical tests that led me to this conjecture:

$$2m+1 \text{ is prime} \iff \exists n:\frac{F_{n}^{2m+1}+F_{n+1}^{2m+1}}{F_{n}+F_{n+1}} \text{ is prime}$$

where $m \ge 1$ and $n \gt 1$.

Therefore, according to the conjecture, if $2m+1$ is composite then $\frac{F_{n}^{2m+1}+F_{n+1}^{2m+1}}{F_{n}+F_{n+1}}$ is composite too for any $n \gt 1$. However, I can't see an easy application of known identities to prove this or the full conjecture.

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1 (generalization)**

This might not be related to Fibonacci numbers, because it seems to work also with e.g. $\frac{(2n+1)^{2m+1}+(3n+1)^{2m+1}}{5n+2}$ so there might be a generalization. The generalization could be: ${2m+1} \space \text{is prime} \space \iff \exists a,b \space\text{coprime} \space : \frac{a^{2m+1}+b^{2m+1}}{a+b} \space\text {is prime}$.

**UPDATE 2 (bound for $n$)**

Maybe the conjecture could be simplified with an upper bound for $n$, although I don't have any idea which bound could be good.

**UPDATE 3 (easier direction proved)**

If $2m+1=uv$, $u,v \gt 1$, then $\frac{a^{uv}+b^{uv}}{a+b}=\frac{a^{uv}+b^{uv}}{a^u+b^u}\frac{a^{u}+b^{u}}{a+b}$, where both fractions on the RHS are integers greater than $1$, therefore $\frac{a^{uv}+b^{uv}}{a+b}$ cannot be prime.

**UPDATE 4**

The more difficult direction will probably remain a conjecture, since there already exist conjectures of this kind e.g.:

$n \space \text{is prime} \implies \exists b: \frac{b^n+1}{b+1} \space \text{is prime}$

(see [OEIS A103795](https://oeis.org/A103795)).

Comment: Your left side depends only on $m$ but your right side depends only on $n$ ($m$ is "bound").

Comment: @aschepler now it is has been edited and fixed.

Comment: Very interesting problem. If the conjecture is correct, I hope to see a full proof of it in the future.

Comment: Maybe a consequence of Dirichlet's thm?

Comment: Is the fraction always a positive integer ?

Comment: Also , where can we stop ? We have infinite many $n$'s to check if no $n$ does the job.

Comment: Wanted to add that we have a very nice (general) formula:
$$\frac{a^{2m+1}+b^{2m+1}}{a+b} = a^{2m}+b^{2m}-ab(a^{2m-2}+b^{2m-2})+a^2b^2(a^{2m-4}+b^{2m-4})-\dots (-1)^ma^mb^m$$
This can be proven by induction. This also answers your first question @Peter.

Comment: @Peter yes, the fraction is always a positive integer: $a^q+b^q = (a+b)(a^{q-1}-a^{q-2}b+a^{q-3}b^2-\cdots+b^{q-1})$ for $q$ odd. Regarding the infinite many $n$ yes, it might be very difficult to prove.

Comment: I am not sure about the statement of this proof. For the prime numbers statement you used the $\exists$ (exists) symbol for $n$ but when talking about composite numbers you say for any $n>1$. Also as @Peter pointed out where can we stop?

Comment: @Ahsan Yousaf $\exists n \gt 1:\frac{F_{n}^{2m+1}+F_{n+1}^{2m+1}}{F_{n}+F_{n+1}} \text{ is prime} \implies 2m+1 \text{ is prime}$ is equivalent to $2m+1 \text{ is composite} \implies \forall n \gt 1:\frac{F_{n}^{2m+1}+F_{n+1}^{2m+1}}{F_{n}+F_{n+1}} \text{ is composite}$. Regarding when we can stop see "UPDATE 2" in the question.

Comment: I have not found the necessary prime for $m=26$ yet.

Comment: @Peter I think there are some primes which are "more difficult", even using generic coprimes $a,b$, for example $29,41,53$ seem to need bigger $a,b$.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote one Mathematica code

```
satisfiedLHSm = (Array[Prime, 100] - 1)/2   // 
  Select[#, IntegerQ] &
f[m_, n_] := 
  PrimeQ[(Fibonacci[n]^(2 m + 1) + 
      Fibonacci[n + 1]^(2 m + 1))/(Fibonacci[n] + Fibonacci[n + 1]) ];
satisfiedRHSm = 
 Flatten[Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 23, 1}, {n, 200}], 1] // 
    Select[#, f @@ # &] & // Map[#[[1]] &, #] & // Union
```

satisfiedLHSm looks like

$$
\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23 \cdots\}
$$

satisfiedRHSm looks like

$$
\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23 \cdots \}
$$

Looks like the conjecture is correct, ... at least for small $m$.